# NGINX location case sensitive

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

```
server {
    listen                    *:443 ssl;
    server_name               www.example.com;

    location /Rst {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5026/Rst;
        expires -1;
    }
```

The user is able to reach my website using https://www.example.com/Rst and https://www.example.com/rst

But I want to ignore the lowercase **rst**. May I know if anyone know what is wrong? I search in the web, seems like NGINX by default should be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression should either start from the “~” symbol for a case-sensitive matching, or from the “~*” symbols (1.0.4) for case-insensitive matching.

```
server {
    listen                    *:443 ssl;
    server_name               www.example.com;

    location ~^/Rst {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5026/Rst;
        expires -1;
    }
```

Comment: I have got the following error
> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in nginx.conf:124